# Rest Controller returns 404 on base path

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to make a REST API with Spring Boot. When I do "http://localhost:8080/foo/*", I get what I want but when I use "http://localhost:8080/api/foo/*", I get 404 error. I have other controllers that are almost the same and they work just fine. I have tried using @RequestMapping but nothing changed.
application.properties:

```
.
.
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public List<Foo> retreiveAllFoos(){
        return fooRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/foo/{id}")
    public Foo retrieveFoo(@PathVariable int id) {
        Optional<Foo> foo = fooRepository.findById(id);
        return foo.get();
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/foo/{id}")
    public void deleteFoo(@PathVariable int id) {
        fooRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createFoo(@RequestBody Foo foo){
        Foo savedFoo = fooRepository.save(foo);
        
        
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedFoo.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/foo/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateFoo(@RequestBody Foo foo, @PathVariable int id){
        Optional<Foo> fooOptional = fooRepository.findById(id);
        
        if(!fooOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        
        foo.setId(id);
        
        fooRepository.save(foo);
        
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct property is `spring.data.rest.basePath` so you want the following in `application.properties`:

```properties
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri

Comment: I changet but the problem still persists.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` include the following:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

However, this will make it by default the root for all endpoints in your application

Also, once you included the `@RequestMapping` annotation are you setting this for the whole controller or the header of each method?